# Prisma - Postgres transaction - problem read incremental number in concurrent transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, prisma

I am currently trying to use the new "interactiveTransactions" preview feature of Prisma. However, it does not seem to actually make my database changes as a transaction.

I am trying to update an incremental number on my school table whenever I create a new report.

This is how my tables look like:

```
model Report {
  id   String @id @default(cuid())
  name String
  publicId Int 
  schoolId String

  school @relation(fields: [schoolId], references: [id])
  @@unique([publicId, schoolId])
}

model School {
  id   String @id @default(cuid())
  name String
  incrementalReportNumber Int @default(1001)

  reports         Report[]
}
```

my code to increment the number whenever I am creating a new report looks like this:

```
 report = await prisma.$transaction(async () => {
      // get current report number
      const school = await prisma.school.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: school.id
        }
      });
      const newIncrementalReportNumber = school.incrementalReportNumber + 1;

      // Increase incrementalReportNumber
      await prisma.school.update({
        where: { id: school.id },
        data: {
          incrementalReportNumber: newIncrementalReportNumber
        }
      });

      // Create report
      const newReport = await prisma.report.create({
        data: {
          publicId: newIncrementalReportNumber,
          name: 'new report'
        },
      });

      // Return
      return newReport;
    });
```

When I create multiple reports at the same time I get an "Unique constraint failed" error,

```
the Error PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`publicId`,`schoolId`)
```

because when I get *incrementalReportNumber*, some process have same value, despite other process already increment it.

I registered the "interactiveTransactions" preview feature with prisma like this:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```

I am using Prisma version "3.2.1"

Comment: Could you please provide details on: 1. Where the value for `newIncrementalReportNumber` is coming from and 2. What your exact Prisma Schema looks like?

Comment: 1. newIncrementalReportNumber is shown in the code.
2. the schema is updated

Comment: Regarding 1: In your code the variable `school` contains the object retreived from the database, but `newIncrementalReportNumber` is assigned to be 1 more than the report number of another object called `theBusiness`, a variable not mentioned anywhere else. Is this a possible bug?

Comment: ah sorry, the code is updated now

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and see if I can identify the issue. Will get back to you if I can identify something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized, that for your specific usecase you could also increment your `incrementalReportNumber` with an [atomic number operation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#atomic-number-operations)

This avoids the need for a stricter transaction isolation level, because you only run update queries and avoid all read queries:

```
 const report = await prisma.$transaction(async (prisma) => {
      const school = await prisma.school.update({
        where: { id: schoolId },
        data: {
          incrementalReportNumber: {
            // increment the report number here
            increment: 1,
          },
        },
      });

      const newReport = await prisma.report.create({
        data: {
          publicId: school.incrementalReportNumber,
          schoolId: school.id,
          name: reportName,
        },
      });

      return newReport;
    });
```

Comment: This is a great solution in my opinion and should solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is with the [transaction isolation level](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#transaction-isolation-level) used by Prisma when running the query.

The default transaction isolation level in Postgres is "read committed", this is what Prisma uses and it does not prevent non-repeatable reads.

##### Non-Repeatable Reads

If you're not sure what non-repeatable reads are, I am adding a good explanation taken from [here](https://logicalread.com/sql-server-concurrency-nonrepeatable-reads-w01/)

> "A non-repeatable read is one in which data read twice inside the same transaction cannot be guaranteed to contain the same value. Depending on the isolation level, another transaction could have nipped in and updated the value between the two reads. 
>  
>  Non-repeatable reads occur because at lower isolation levels reading data only locks the data for the duration of the read, rather than for the duration of the transaction"

In your case, the following race condition might be happening due to non-repeatable reads.

1. **Transaction B**: Read school data with report number x and increment to x + 1.
2. **Transaction A**: Read school data with report number x and increment to x + 1.
3. **Transaction B**: Commit report number x + 1 to database.
4. **Transaction A**: Attempt to create report with x+1 report number and fail.

*Unfortunately, Prisma does not currently support changing the transaction isolation level.* So, you might need to come to some other workaround for this issue (possibly even writing raw SQL code).

We have a [feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8668) for exactly this and I would really urge you to comment your problem over there. That way it would help us track demand for this feature and incentivize adding it quickly.